# How to show the results for the last three months?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am developing a training management web-based system which will show the management the training record for each division. My database design is like following:

> Employee Table: Username, Name, Job, DivisionID
>
> Division Table: DivisionID, DivisionName
>
> Quiz Table: QuizID, Title, Description
>
> UserQuiz Table: UserQuizID, Score, DateTimeComplete, QuizID, Username

**NOTE:** The first attribute in each table is the primary key.

The SQL Query that I am using for this task is:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT dbo.UserQuiz.QuizID) AS [Total Number of Quizzes], 
  dbo.Divisions.DivisionName, 
  DATENAME(Month, dbo.UserQuiz.DateTimeComplete) AS Month 
FROM dbo.UserQuiz 
INNER JOIN dbo.Quiz 
  ON dbo.UserQuiz.QuizID = dbo.Quiz.QuizID 
INNER JOIN  dbo.employee 
  ON dbo.UserQuiz.Username = dbo.employee.Username 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.Divisions 
  ON dbo.employee.DivisionCode = dbo.Divisions.SapCode 
GROUP BY dbo.Divisions.DivisionName,
  DATENAME(Month, dbo.UserQuiz.DateTimeComplete)
```

This query will show me the total number of taken quizzes by each division based on month. What I want now is showing these results for the last three months. Also, I want to show all the divisions even if there is a division which does not take any quiz. This means I want to show the division with zero number of taken quizzes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For showing ALL Divisions, that will need to be first in the list, then LEFT JOINed to the count results.  You'll need to COALESCE() the value so if null, will return the zero instead.  As for the last 3 months, you'll just need to add a WHERE clause for the date range.

Edit... per comment.  I've taken it one step further and for each division, I've created it as a Cross-Tab to show the division with 3 columns showing the counts of each respective month in a single row...  So, the resulting column names would be the same, but would reflect the actual month data content...   Actually adjusted the WHERE clause going back only 2 months... 2 months back plus current equals 3 months total.

```
 select 
          d.DivisionName,
          SUM( case when PreQuery.ByMonth = DATENAME(Month, DateAdd( month, -2, GetDate())
                    then PreQuery.DistinctQuizes else 0 end ) as TwoMonthsAgoCount,
          SUM( case when PreQuery.ByMonth = DATENAME(Month, DateAdd( month, -1, GetDate())
                    then PreQuery.DistinctQuizes else 0 end ) as OneMonthAgoCount,
          SUM( case when PreQuery.ByMonth = DATENAME(Month, GetDate())
                    then PreQuery.DistinctQuizes else 0 end ) as CurrentMonthCount
       from
          Divisions d
             left join
             ( select count( distinct UQ.QuizID ) DistinctQuizes,
                     DATENAME(Month, UQ.DateTimeComplete) ByMonth,
                      d2.DivisionName
                  from 
                     UserQuiz UQ
                        JOIN Quiz Q on UQ.QuizID = Q.QuizID
                        JOIN Employee E on UQ.UserName = E.UserName
                           JOIN Divisions D2 on E.DivisionCode = D2.SapCode
                  where
                    UQ.DateTimeComplete between 
                        DateAdd( month, -2, GetDate())  and GetDate() 
                  group by 
                     d2.DivisionName,
                     DATENAME(Month, UQ.DateTimeComplete)
             ) PreQuery
             ON d.DivisionName = PreQuery.DivisionName
   GROUP BY
      d.DivisionName
```

By using "GetDate()", this returns whatever the current date is on the computer.  This would be the ENDING date.  The first date would be basic date arithmetic...  Use the DateAdd function, add an interval based on months of -2 (negative to go BACKWARDS), based on whatever the current date is.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I got an error when I tried to execute this query. The error was: Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 22
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','.

Comment: @MohammedAl-Ali, my oops... last should have been an = for the "ON" clause.  Missed it as I was on my way out with family this morning.  I also added the COALESCE()

Comment: I could not be able to determine the date in the WHERE clause. FYI, I will use query for generating a chart in ASP.NET. This chart should be dynamic which means it should automatically show different results based on the last three months. For example, if I go to this chart tomorrow, it should show me a result for the last three months started from tomorrow's date. So how to do that?

Comment: @MohammedAl-Ali, see revised answer using GetDate() and DateAdd()

Comment: Thank you a lot but there is something which I did not get it by this query. The query should show me the results of all divisions in the each month of the three months. For example, if I have six divisions, the query should show me these divisions in December, November, October with the total number of taken quizzes which it may 0 or any number

Comment: And sorry for asking you a lot, but this kind of queries are new to me. Hope you can resolve the above issue. And in all cases, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @MohammedAl-Ali, finished, and even added into a cross-tab

Comment: Thanks a lot. I really appreciate your help. I got a red color under (then) and up to now I could not be able to execute the query but I am working on it.