# Why I got an error with this query?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following query which should show result for the last 3 months:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT dbo.UserQuiz.QuizID) AS [Total Number of Quizzes],
   dbo.Divisions.DivisionName, 
   DATENAME(Month, dbo.UserQuiz.DateTimeComplete) AS Month 
FROM dbo.UserQuiz 
INNER JOIN dbo.Quiz 
  ON dbo.UserQuiz.QuizID = dbo.Quiz.QuizID 
INNER JOIN dbo.employee 
  ON dbo.UserQuiz.Username = dbo.employee.Username 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.Divisions 
  ON dbo.employee.DivisionCode = dbo.Divisions.SapCode 

GROUP BY dbo.Divisions.DivisionName, 
  DATENAME(Month, dbo.UserQuiz.DateTimeComplete) 
HAVING (DATENAME(Month, GETDATE()) - 
        DATENAME(Month, dbo.UserQuiz.DateTimeComplete) > 3
```

The problem now with this query is when I tried to execute it in the SQLServer Management Studio 2008 R2, I got the following error and I don't why:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5 Incorrect syntax near '3'.

Comment: Good formatting may improve readabilty and might increase chances to get a good answer.

Comment: I can't believe you asked this question.

Answer (score 2):

You need an end parenthesis after the 3.

```
SELECT     
    COUNT(DISTINCT dbo.UserQuiz.QuizID) AS [Total Number of Quizzes],   
    dbo.Divisions.DivisionName, 
    DATENAME(Month, dbo.UserQuiz.DateTimeComplete)  AS Month 

FROM dbo.UserQuiz 

INNER JOIN dbo.Quiz 
ON dbo.UserQuiz.QuizID = dbo.Quiz.QuizID 

INNER JOIN dbo.employee 
ON dbo.UserQuiz.Username = dbo.employee.Username 

RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.Divisions 
ON dbo.employee.DivisionCode = dbo.Divisions.SapCode 

GROUP BY dbo.Divisions.DivisionName, 
DATENAME(Month, dbo.UserQuiz.DateTimeComplete) 

HAVING (
    DATENAME(Month, GETDATE()) 
    - DATENAME(Month, dbo.UserQuiz.DateTimeComplete) > 3
) -- you were missing this parenthesis
```

Comment: I got this error: Operand data type nvarchar is invalid for subtract operator.

Comment: That's right, you can't subtract nvarchars. You might need to cast them to an int.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to do?

Comment: I already did. Please see it on this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8462792/how-to-modify-this-query-to-show-all-the-divisions-in-the-last-three-months

Answer (score 0):

I believe you miss a ')' in you having somewhere.

```
HAVING (DATENAME(Month, GETDATE()) - DATENAME(Month, dbo.UserQuiz.DateTimeComplete) > 3
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: I got an error, too. It is Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Line 20
Operand data type nvarchar is invalid for subtract operator.